# osm2pgsql style not applied

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have downloaded OSM in pdf format and are using the code below to import it into postGIS

```
osm2pgsql -K -G -U postgres -W --hstore --style ~PATH\osm\openstreetmap-carto.style --tag-transform-script ~PATH\openstreetmap-carto.lua -d osm ~PATH\osm\west-midlands-latest.osm.pbf
```

I have got the style files from https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/INSTALL.md

When I add my layers to QGIS no style seem to be applied to the layer, am I missing something? I was expexted it to look similar to http://www.openstreetmap.org/ am I missing something obvious?
 [image]

Comment: Please see the [README](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/README.md): *These stylesheets can be used in your own cartography projects, and are designed to be easily customised. They work with Kosmtik and also with the command-line CartoCSS processor.* What you see in QGIS is the raw data only!

Comment: You are right, I missed that, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the file is called `style`, it is not a rendering style like you apply on QGIS layers. It is just a filter on the OSM raw data ro be passed into the Postgis database.

You still need rendering styles inside QGIS, like you find in https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/qgis2/osm_spatialite. Note that these are for a spatialite database, so Postgis field names may be different.